# What is the simplest way to list fields of a struct in procedural derive Rust macros?

Tags: rust, macros

I want to write a derive macro for structs which will generate another struct with the same fields but wrapped in `Option`.

For example:

```
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct Struct {
    field_1: String,
    field_2: Vec<String>,
    field_3: f32,
}
```

Generated struct:

```
pub struct StructBuilder {
    field_1: Option<String>,
    field_2: Option<Vec<String>>,
    field_3: Option<f32>,
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder)]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let _input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let name = _input.ident;
    let name_builder = Ident::new(&format!("{}Builder", name.to_string()), Span::call_site());
    let Data::Struct(data) = _input.data;
    let mut fields  = proc_macro2::TokenStream::new();
    let mut expanded = proc_macro2::TokenStream::new();
    expanded.extend(quote!(pub struct #name_builder));
    for field in data.fields {
        let field_name = field.ident.unwrap();
        let field_type = field.ty;
        fields.extend(quote!(#field_name: Option<#field_type>,))
    }
    expanded.extend(TokenTree::from(Group::new(Delimiter::Brace, fields)));
    expanded.into()
}
```

But it doesn't even compile.

So I want to know two things:

1. How to add new lines of code in the TokenStream?
   I'm not sure that I use `extend` method correctly.
2. How to insert generated fields between braces `{ ... }`?
   Also not sure that I use `expanded.extend(TokenTree::from(Group::new(Delimiter::Brace, fields)));` correctly.
   This also doesn't work:

```
expanded.extend(quote!(pub struct #name_builder {));
    ...
expanded.extend(quote!(}));
```

I'll be happy to receive any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax where you extract the `data` from `_input.data` seems to be slightly off. Let's fix that first.

```
let syn::Data::Struct(data) = _input.data else {
  unimplemented!()
};
```

I would not recommend using the `extend` method. Instead use `quote!` to create a top-level `TokenStream` and then nest other token streams into it where appropriate.

Let's iterate over the `fields` and create a `TokenStream` for each field.

```
let fields = data.fields.iter().map(|f| {
  let name = &f.ident;
  let ty = &f.ty;
  quote! {
    #name: Option<#ty>
  }
});
```

We can now nest the field token streams into our top-level `expanded` token stream and return it.

```
let expanded = quote! (
  pub struct #name_builder {
    #(#fields,)*
  }
);

expanded.into()
```

---

Here is the full function for reference:

```
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder, attributes(builder))]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let _input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let name = _input.ident;
    let name_builder = Ident::new(&format!("{}Builder", name.to_string()), Span::call_site());

    let data = if let syn::Data::Struct(data) = _input.data {
        data
    } else {
        unimplemented!();
    };

    let fields = data.fields.iter().map(|f| {
        let name = &f.ident;
        let ty = &f.ty;
        quote! {
            #name: Option<#ty>
        }
    });

    let expanded = quote! (
        pub struct #name_builder {
            #(#fields,)*
        }
    );

    expanded.into()
}
```

Input:

```
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct Struct {
    field_1: String,
    field_2: Vec<String>,
    field_3: f32,
}
```

Output:

```
pub struct Struct {
    field_1: String,
    field_2: Vec<String>,
    field_3: f32,
}
pub struct StructBuilder {
    field_1: Option<String>,
    field_2: Option<Vec<String>>,
    field_3: Option<f32>,
}
```